# Prove by induction that the $n$-th derivative of $\cos(x)$ is given by $\cos\left(x+n\frac{\pi }{2}\right)$

Tags: trigonometry, induction, proof-explanation

Given the function $f\left(x\right)=\cos(x)$. Prove by induction that for $\forall n\in \mathbb{N}$ $f^{(n)}=\cos\bigl(x+n\cdot \frac{\pi }{2}\bigr)$. Being that $f^{\left(1\right)}$ is the first derivative and so forth.

Comment: What do you need us to explain ? (except doing the entire proof for you )

Comment: I'm learning math all on my own. If you think it useful to do the proof for me in order for me to understand and and continue with my learning, then, by all means, do it. My resources are very limited otherwise...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well as requested, i will detail a little more the sketch of the proof.
Induction proof is like domino's : you need to check that the first domino falls ( true for $n=0$ here ) and then you have to check that the $n-$th domino makes the $n+1-$th fall.
Here : check the case $n=0$.
You have
$$
\cos\left(x+0.\frac{\pi}{2}\right)=\cos\left(x\right)=f^{\left(0\right)}\left(x\right)
$$
So the given relation is true. Now suppose that it is true until a certain rank $n$, then you need to consider $f^{\left(n+1\right)}(x)$. You have
$$
f^{\left(n+1\right)}(x)=\left(f^{\left(n\right)}\left(x\right)\right)'=\left(\cos\left(x+n\frac{\pi}{2}\right)\right)'=-\sin\left(x+n\frac{\pi}{2}\right)=\cos\left(x+\frac{\pi}{2}+n\frac{\pi}{2}\right)
$$
The last equality comes from $\displaystyle \cos\left(x+\frac{\pi}{2}\right)=-\sin\left(x\right)$ ( check a trigonometric circle to see this ).
Hence we've shown

> $$
> f^{\left(n+1\right)}(x)=\cos\left(x+\left(n+1\right)\frac{\pi}{2}\right)
> $$

The relation is hence TRUE at rank $n+1$.
By induction the relation is true for ALL $n$.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a proof that doesn't use a recurrence.

I give it because it can be rather appealing under the condition to have some practice with complex numbers.

Let us start from the famous De Moivre formula :

$$\cos(x)+i \sin(x)=e^{ix} \tag{1}$$

$n$ times differentiation of both sides gives :

$$\cos^{(n)}(x)+i \sin^{(n)}(x)=i^n e^{ix}\tag{2}$$

The RHS of (2) can be transformed

$$\cos^{(n)}(x)+i \sin^{(n)}(x)=e^{i\tfrac{\pi}{2}n}e^{ix}=e^{i(x+\tfrac{\pi}{2}n)}\tag{3}$$

Using anew De Moivre formula, we get :

$$\cos^{(n)}(x)+i \sin^{(n)}(x)=\cos(x+\tfrac{\pi}{2}n)+i\sin(x+\tfrac{\pi}{2}n)\tag{4}$$

Taking the real part of both sides terminates the proof.

Comment: This is the sort of thing that made me love mathematics!

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

You just have to know that the first derivative, $f'(x)=-\sin x$, can be written as
$$f'(x)=\sin\bigl(x+\tfrac\pi 2\bigr)$$
from a well-known trigonometry formula, then an easy induction will complete the proof.